# Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 when trying to run on android flutter

Tags: flutter

When I try to run on an android real device or simulator it gives this in flutter .
It is just the basic flutter example app , Everything is ok on flutter doctor , and it fails when I try flutter doctor --android-license

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
at   sun.net.     www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient
(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect
(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream
(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
event sent after app closed: {id: 0, progressId: null, message: Running "flutter pub get"
in socialapp...}
event sent after app closed: {id: 0, progressId: null, finished: true}
Launching lib/main.dart on SM N960F in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you include your `flutter doctor` output for more detail on the bug?

Comment: [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.3)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available